# Finding the big O Notations of LZMA2 and BWT compression algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, compression, big-o, complexity-theory, notation

I am writing an essay about the Lemepel Ziv Markov chain Algorithm chain 2 and the burrows wheeler transform, but I cannot find the Big O notations for these algorithms. I looked for pseudo code for both, through source code and yet I still cant find the notation. I can only access the LZMA2 Java code, however it is littered with methods from the program I accessed it by (not the IDE). I cannot find the complete raw algorithms for neither of these two algorithms, is there another way I can determine the notation?

Is there a method just by looking at the way they function as compression algorithms?

Thank you very much! Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the abstract at http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/892706/: "Like the BWT-based codes, the proposed algorithm requires worst case O(n) computational complexity..."

Comment: There isn't just one way to compute the BWT, there are linear-time ways to do it, quadratic-time ways, and various in between (some log n factors appear).

Comment: Oh so no generalised term? How can I access the code to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n). These methods all work with some fixed block size, with some corresponding approximately constant time to compress a block. So the total time is simply linear in the input size.

Comment: thank you, and is a block the segment of data being compressed- so for the lzma the 'window'?

Comment: It's related. As I recall the default block size is four times the window size.